# Adding a programmatically created custom view into multiple layouts

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have programmatically created a custom view in android.And want to add this same view into two relative layouts of same activity without removing view's parent layout.

Here is my xml code-

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"          
        android:background="@drawable/right"
        android:id="@+id/one"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/right"
        android:id="@+id/two"         
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java code-

```
            p = new PathView(this);  //Custom View 
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);                 
                    b[x][y].addView(p);
                }}
```

Whenever I clicked on second times its getting error to remove parent layout from view.But I don't want to remove.Please help me to overcome from this problem.

Comment: what is "b" . share some code explanatory code. Is your parent layout

Comment: "b" is an array in which both relative layouts are defined.And all click events are performed by this array b[x][y].